# jQuery - How to get image from div when click on it

Tags: jquery

Here, I' want to implement some code to get the images when click on it.So,some example code that used.

```
<div class="click"><img class="img1"  src ="img/1.png"/></div>
<div class="click"><img class="img2"  src ="img/2.png"/></div>

  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.click).click(function(){
       // some code will be implement here
       $('.content').html();
    });
});

<div class="content"></div> <!-- the image will show here -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone the image:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.click').click(function () {
        var $img = $(this).find('img').clone();
        $('.content').html($img);
    });

});
```

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry if something happen here,but you all helped me and I have voted both answers. :peace: :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.click').click(function() {
  $('.content').html($(this).find('img').clone());
});
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/zuweko/1/edit?html,js,output)